# Visual Studio Code is not showing alert for undefined class methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, linter, pylance

I am using vscode with Pylance and Pylint, and it does not show an alert for undefined class methods as Pycharm does.

Example:

**Pycharm**

[image: Pycharm example]

**Visual Studio Code**

[image: Visual Studio Code example]

**What I tried:**

- Used a different linter (Flake 8)
- Made sure there are no settings that might disable that specific linter error
- Selected the linter (`cmd+shift+p` > select linter)

Is there's any way to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you clear all settings and make sure `pylint` is installed. Then enable linting and select `pylint` to see if it works.

*Adding the following configuration to the **setting.json** has the same effect:*

```json
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```